# How to deploy Kong to docker swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, database-migration, docker-swarm, kong

Followed [official guide](https://docs.konghq.com/install/docker/) to write a stack deploy file:

stack.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  kong-database:
    image: cassandra:3
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
    networks:
      - kong-net

  kong-migration:
    image: kong:latest
    depends_on:
      - kong-database
    environment:
      - KONG_DATABASE=cassandra
      - KONG_CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS=kong-database
    command: kong migrations up
    networks:
      - kong-net

  kong:
    image: kong:latest
    depends_on:
      - kong-database
      - kong-migration
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
    environment:
      - KONG_DATABASE=cassandra
      - KONG_CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS=kong-database
      - KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout
      - KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout
      - KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr
      - KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr
      - KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "8443:8443"
      - "8001:8001"
      - "8444:8444"
    networks:
      - kong-net

networks:
  kong-net:
```

Deploy:

```
$ docker stack deploy -c stack.yml gateway
```

Check services:

```
$ docker service ls
ID                  NAME                      MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                                             PORTS
xg3qld08ziio        gateway_kong              replicated          1/3                 kong:latest                                       *:8000-8001->8000-8001/tcp, *:8443-8444->8443-8444/tcp
kam7fw265ons        gateway_kong-database     replicated          1/1                 cassandra:3                                       *:9042->9042/tcp
kr0vqoc66izn        gateway_kong-migration    replicated          0/1                 kong:latest
```

Check `gateway_kong` log:

```
gateway_kong.2.zn0tfalwxylx@ip-1-2-3-4    |        [C]: in function 'error'
gateway_kong.2.zxuwxm5xbroe@ip-1-2-3-4    |        init_by_lua:3: in main chunk
gateway_kong.2.zxuwxm5xbroe@ip-1-2-3-4    | nginx: [error] init_by_lua error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:172: [cassandra error] the current database schema does not match this version of Kong. Please run `kong migrations up` to update/initialize the database schema. Be aware that Kong migrations should only run from a single node, and that nodes running migrations concurrently will conflict with each other and might corrupt your database schema!
gateway_kong.1.zr8biqoaccfz@ip-1-2-3-4    |        init_by_lua:3: in main chunk
gateway_kong.1.zy0u3ul9gp0l@ip-1-2-3-4    |        init_by_lua:3: in main chunk
gateway_kong.2.zn0tfalwxylx@ip-1-2-3-4    |        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:169: in function 'init'
gateway_kong.1.zy0u3ul9gp0l@ip-1-2-3-4    | nginx: [error] init_by_lua error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:172: [cassandra error] the current database schema does not match this version of Kong. Please run `kong migrations up` to update/initialize the database schema. Be aware that Kong migrations should only run from a single node, and that nodes running migrations concurrently will conflict with each other and might corrupt your database schema!
gateway_kong.2.zxuwxm5xbroe@ip-1-2-3-4    | stack traceback:
gateway_kong.2.zxuwxm5xbroe@ip-1-2-3-4    |        [C]: in function 'assert'
gateway_kong.2.zn0tfalwxylx@ip-1-2-3-4    |        init_by_lua:3: in main chunk
gateway_kong.1.zy0u3ul9gp0l@ip-1-2-3-4    | stack traceback:
gateway_kong.1.zy0u3ul9gp0l@ip-1-2-3-4    |        [C]: in function 'assert'
gateway_kong.2.zxuwxm5xbroe@ip-1-2-3-4    |        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:172: in function 'init'
gateway_kong.2.zxuwxm5xbroe@ip-1-2-3-4    |        init_by_lua:3: in main chunk
gateway_kong.1.zy0u3ul9gp0l@ip-1-2-3-4    |        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:172: in function 'init'
gateway_kong.1.zy0u3ul9gp0l@ip-1-2-3-4    |        init_by_lua:3: in main chunk
gateway_kong.3.zq9rrsn2pd2r@ip-1-2-3-5    |       /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:172: in function 'init'
gateway_kong.3.zq9rrsn2pd2r@ip-1-2-3-5    |       init_by_lua:3: in main chunk
```

Have defined `kong-migration` and set command `kong migrations up`. Even set depends `depends_on`, why can't do migration?

Comment: what you have changed from the tutorial?

Comment: @ShiheZhang Added `depends_on`. I think that's all.

Comment: @vv I know I am late to the party but in version 3 of YAML depends on is deprecated and it's not backward compatible according to docker documents. Depends on functionality can be achieved using a shell script as mention on docker's documentation. Were you able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

As there is no answer here I will leave some things that I learned recently even if it's not related to Kong. This question seems more related to container startup order than to Kong itself.

[The depends_on option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode with a version 3 Compose file.](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on)

I tried to deploy Traefik with configuration stored in Consul to Swarm.
The scenario was:

- I had to deploy first my storage backend: `consul`
- Then deploy an instance of traefik which would upload config to consul: `traefik_init`
- And finally I could deploy all traefik instances with consul backend:  `traefik`

I was not able to deploy `consul`, `traefik_init` and `traefik` in the same stack.
Since I was alreay using Ansible I created a playbook doing the following

- deploy `consul` stack
- wait for all consul nodes to be synced
- start `traefik_init` as a service with only 1 replica
- wait for the configuration to be stored in consul
- deploy `traefik` stack.

I could have deployed all services in same stack if I chose to override both `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` of containers to use a script that wait for needed services to be up and then execute command at startup.

If I were not using Ansible already I would definitely have gone that way.

You can take a look at [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) (pure bash script to test and wait on the availability of a TCP host and port) or [wait-for](https://github.com/Eficode/wait-for)(script to wait for another service to become available) for examples.

You can also find an example at https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/